# Web crawling few websites and searching their content

Tags: java, search-engine, web-crawler

I intend to build a service that provides summarized contents of specific webpages in specific websites.

So instead of depending on Google or Bing APIs (that costs money), I thought of searching for a web crawler and a search engine that could do this job. I need it only for a small scale so Apache Nutch for example is too big for the project.

The ideal solution would be an embeddable library that gets list of websites, acquires their contents and save them in a db for later search. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you intend to build a service that summarizes web content? Here are some APIs that you can use to do that:

- https://www.mashape.com/stremor/stremor-automated-summary-and-abstract-generator
- https://www.mashape.com/stremor/stremor-search-results
- https://www.mashape.com/stremor/stremor-tldr-for-text-abstract-generator
- https://www.mashape.com/mlanalyzer/ml-analyzer
- https://www.mashape.com/tommoor/pagemunch

And a few of my own:

- https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/summarize-css
- https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/summarizer-tool

The last 2 were based on this excellent tutorial on how to create your own summarizer - http://thetokenizer.com/2013/04/28/build-your-own-summary-tool/

Comment: +1 for summary tutorial.

Comment: The point isn't in summarizing. That's beyond the scope of my questions. Good links though.

Answer (score 1):

crawler and indexer are typically two separate components.

- For crawling, you can use crawler4j take a look https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/ .
  It's simple but I think it covers some of the functionalities you are looking for. You may need to use a JDBC call to save the results but it does the crawling for you well.
- For indexing you can use lucene take a look at http://lucene.apache.org/core/.

I also recommend taking a look at North Western University that describes this way much better than I can...so here is the [link](http://search.northwestern.edu/help/webmasters/crawling-and-indexing.html) for you

Comment: Yes, it's a good library. Though, it's not clear to me how to save/index and search the data. Any ideas?

Comment: @M-T-A crawler and indexers are typically two separate components. I have updated the above information for you. Hope this helps.